# android studio- selecting which radio button was pressed in a radio group is not working

Tags: android-studio

current uni student and I am working on a simple pizza app to consolidate my knowledge on radio buttons and groups

I have a radio group and inside I have 3 buttons, I am then trying to print which radio button was pressed inside my text view.

Here is the XML code for the radio group/button

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.939"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tomato"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="tomato"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.079"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.664" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/chilli"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="chilli"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.412"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.664" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/BBQ"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="BBQ"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.74"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.664" />
    </RadioGroup> 
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sauce"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sauce"
        android:onClick="showSelectedItem"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.517"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.691" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/sauceResult"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.92" />
```

then my java code is the following:

```
public void showSelectedItem(View view){
        RadioGroup rg = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        RadioButton rb;
        int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb = view.findViewById(id);
        TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.sauceResult);
        text.setText("your sauce is: " + rb.getText());
    }
```

my current output is when I select an option and press the button to display the text the app closes and the prompt displayed is "tut3_1 has closed unexpectedly"

Answer (score 0):

set this

```
rb = view.findViewById(id);
TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.sauceResult);
```

before

```
int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Comment: this makes no sense?
if i swap the order then rb = view.findViewById(id) would throw an error has i havent declared id

Comment: you are using wrong id  binding   declare      rb = findViewById(id);
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.sauceResult);  in Oncreate Method  and don't use  
 view.findViewById(id) you just need to use findViewById(...)

Comment: i am using a basic activity so im on the first_fragment.java page